# Can a point in the quantum set of correlations violate more than one independent facet Bell inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, bells-inequality, non-locality

Usually, depictions of the quantum set of correlations and the local polytope look something like:
[image]
In this image it looks like non-local points belonging to the quantum set (in yellow) violate only one facet Bell inequality at a time. It also looks like the "vertices" or "edges" of the local polytope reach the bound of the quantum set. Is this actually the case or are depictions of the quantum and classical set of correlations like this one just a bit misleading?

Edit: As glS mentioned in their comment, in the 2-dimensional case there's a single nontrivial inequality, so any non-local point will violate one, and therefore all, independent Bell inequalities characterising the classical polytope. I was wondering if this is true in general for arbitrary dimension.

Comment: that "vertices of the local polytope reach the bound of the quantum set" is true: these correspond to "trivial Bell inequalities", where the max obtained by classical and quantum behaviors concides. Remember "Bell inequalities" in this context are just linear combinations of conditional probability distributions, so each such combination is a direction. As a trivial example, consider the "Bell inequality" $0\le p(00|00)\le1$. This would correspond to a direction where the boundary of classical and quantum sets concide

Comment: the other part of the question is trickier IMO. With "violate only one facet Bell inequality at a time" I assume you mean writing the complete set of inequalities characterising the classical polytope (otherwise you can always consider trivial modifications of a Bell inequality which will still capture some non-classical state. In the standard 2-2 case there's a single nontrivial inequality, so the answer is trivially positive in this situation. But more generally, I'm not sure

Comment: @glS That is exactly what I meant. I knew it was true in the 2-dimensional case, but I was wondering if it was true in general. Thanks for your answer anyway!